# Is it possible to seamlessly display an ajax spinner for every GWT RPC call?

Tags: ajax, gwt, rpc, spinner

I have a GWT application that uses RPC calls heavily. I would like to display a spinner icon whenever a call is in progress. It is easy enough to display the icon, but I want to do it seamlessly in one place so I don't have to explicitly hide and show the icon for each call.

I guess I am looking for something similar to jQuery's ajaxStart and ajaxStop events.

Has anyone done something like this before?

Cheers
Tin

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you implement this behaviour in a concrete implementation of AsyncCallback and subclass all the AsyncCallbacks from this one. Alternatively you could use a decorator pattern where you use a regular AsyncCallback and decorate it with another one that shows/hides the popup.

Alternatively, if you use a Command Pattern, you could just add these events to your command pattern implementation and you can register a handler that shows/hides a popup every time a request is send/received.

Comment: I think decorator pattern is the best way to implement this. But I would like to see this as a standard thing provided by GWT in some later version.

Comment: I guess I would need both. An AsyncCallback base class that handles the stopping of the spinner as well as a decorator class for each async interface. The problem is, I have a lot of different async interfaces and it would be a mess to try and wrap all of them seperately. Any ideas on how I could do it generically?

In standard java, AOP would solve this kind of thing but I'm not sure whether there is a GWT equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In response to comments that suggest a Decorator is not enough.

```
abstract class AbstractAsyncCallback <T> implements AsyncCallaback <T>
{
 public AbstractAsyncCallback ()
 {
  Foo.showIcon();
 }

 @Override public void success (T t)
 {
  doSuccess(t);
  Foo.hideIcon();
 }

 @Override public void failure ()
 {
  doFailure();
  Foo.hideIcon();
 }

 public abstract void doSuccess (T t);

 public abstract void doFailure (T t);
};
```